# Ошибка подключения библиотеки к Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, библиотеки

Вообщем не получается подключить opencv к Qt Creator, вылезает ошибка, хотя вроде все правильно.

Предоставляю содержимое файла pro, пробовал подключать по разному, в данном случае использовал встроенный менеджер подключения.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-04-22T22:00:41
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = open_cv_test
TEMPLATE = app
# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h


FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/ -lopencv_world341
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/ -lopencv_world341d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/build/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/build/include

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/libopencv_world341.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/libopencv_world341d.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world341.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world341d.lib
```

[image: Сама ошибка выглядит таким образом, при этом все файлы hpp библиотеки можно открывать и читать прямо в редакторе, как и все типы, классы и прочее подключились.]

Сама ошибка выглядит таким образом, при этом все файлы hpp библиотеки можно открывать и читать прямо в редакторе, как и все типы, классы и прочее подключились.

Comment: А что пишет компилятор? (Вкладка "Компиляция") Бывает, что в таких ситуациях помогает очистка проекта, запуск `qmake`.

Comment: @mkkik все сработало, спасибо большое, очистил проект, и запустил qmake, после этого все собралось, большое спасибо!